# IOS how to hide the top bar (with done button) on the top of the keyboard?

Tags: ios, delphi, uitextfield, firemonkey, uikeyboard

I have an `UITextField`, and when the keyboard is show, their is on the top on it a bar with a "`done`" button.

[image]

This done button is totally useless, first it's duplicate the done button already present in the keyboard and second it's not fire the event `ShouldReturn` making hard to trap any action with it.

also i see this button on my iphone 5 + ios 9 but i not seeing it on my ipad pro + ios 10

I m using delphi, i don't know if it's matter (other app on my iphone 5 not made with delphi don't have this "done" bar so maybe yes)

Comment: You should remove accessory view from keypad. or try this one yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = nil;

Comment: thanks @RajJoshi. i try to set TextField.inputAccessoryView = nil; just after creating the textField but it's didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i found the problem. i was suspicious when i saw that the caption of the button (done) not change on french iphone. apple will not do such horrible mistake, but it's typically what can do the emb team :( And yes this bar is made by delphi ! don't ask me why they do a such horrible think by default, but they did ... and it's was not showing in the ipad because :

```
procedure TCocoaVirtualKeyboardService.ApplicationEventHandler(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  if (M is TApplicationEventMessage) and ((M as TApplicationEventMessage).Value.Event = TApplicationEvent.FinishedLaunching) then
  begin
    FToolbarEnabled := not IsPad;
    FHideButtonVisible := FToolbarEnabled;
  end;
end;
```

really great nawak :(

so you can disable the toolbar by doing :

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardToolbarService, aVirtualKeyboardToolbarService) then aVirtualKeyboardToolbarService.SetToolbarEnabled(False);
```

completely idiot to make this useless and ugly toolbar enabled by default :(

Comment: If someone wonders (just like me) where to call it. You could call this in the FormCreate event. You don't need to call it multiple times.